# would have passed the exam already

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Let's say you are a lawyer, and just made a comment on the difficulty of lawyers' bar exam.

> If the bar exam is easy, many **would have passed** it already.

Is this grammatical? the bar exam is quite challenging, the situation started in the past and is still re-occuring over and over again because many have re-attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the sentence you highlight is syntactically correct—but in terms of semantics you should use some kind of comparative.

Also, you need to use the [subjunctive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive) in the first part of the sentence.

In summary, I would suggest this:

> If the bar exam ***were*** easy, many ***more*** would have passed it already.